# VB6 loading c# COM UserControl scaling UI

Tags: c#, com, vb6

I have a C# .NET 4.7.1 User control.
It is a WinForms user control loading a WPF user control through an element host object, however I have removed the element host and the problem seems to remain.

I am loading this user control into an existing VB6 application (to replace an existing control and gain additional features) running on Windows 10 (development), and Windows 10 LTSC (production).

I have the control loading and everything is working correctly following the tutorial here
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18954/Interop-Forms-Toolkit-2-0-Tutorial
And using code from this repo
https://github.com/froque/interoptoolkitcs/blob/master/main/src/Templates/CSInteropUserControlProjectTemplate/ActiveXControlHelpers.cs

The issue is when the Windows Display settings have been adjusted to have a scaling factor of something larger than 100%.
The VB6 IDE when opening the designer, or when running the application in the IDE, it will cause the IDE and application to shrink.
This also happens when running the built application.

I have not tried a smaller scaling factor to see what happens.

My monitors are high resolution, 2160x3840 so I set my scaling factor to 125% and a colleague has his set high as well.
There is no guarantee our end users have the scaling factor set to 100% so I would like to solve this before releasing it.

I have tried different settings using the app.config file but these haven't made any difference.
DpiAware
DpiAwareness
EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing

Changing the compatibility settings of the IDE didn't seem to make any change.

I have also tried adding Application.EnableVisualStyles() to the constructor of my WinForm control but this also hasn't had any effect.

Comment: You do realize that VB6 went out of support in 2008, right? In 2008, top-end monitors were 22 inches and 1,680 x 1,050 (https://www.crn.com/slide-shows/components-peripherals/212201934/12-recommended-displays-from-2008.htm). In 1998, when it shipped, a 1024x768 19" CRT was more than what most folks could afford.

Comment: _"I am loading this user control into an existing VB6 application"_ - there is the mistake you need to work on.

Comment: ...and how many VB6 apps are still in production in 2023?   Usually these apps cannot be replaced wholesale, rather they are updated piece by piece as the OP is attempting to do.

Comment: You should be able to force the app to behave normally (ie: not support hi-dpi but have a somewhat blurred but correctly sized app rendered) with application configuration. This is not the app.config that governs that but the app manifest (or by code). Difficult to help more w/o some real code. Please provide a complete reproducible sample https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: So an update, as @SimonMourier has mentioned I have been able to get this to work by using a manifest file embedded into the resource file, but as mentioned it does stretch everything making it blurry, alternative I found under the compatibility options of windows you can tell it to use the Application DPI rather than System. While this stops the shrinking, it does cause some other artifacts with our buttons (Which are hacked up checkboxes to get them to look better). Today I also noticed the WinForm test application I wrote which loads the WinForm user control was also doing the shrinking,

Comment: To those mentioning VB6 is out of support etc. I am well aware of this, but thanks for the insightful opinion, and Microsoft's official statement is "It just works" so the IDE is out of support but the run time is not. 
The application has been in production for 25 years. With a failed big bang port to c# a few years back (The VB6 version was\is still under development so we were forever chasing a moving goal post) so our only approach is to do it slowly over time.

Comment: Unless you provide code to look at, the blurry strech is probably the best you can do with VB6 as the host, it's exactly the "it just works" way for legacy apps/frameworks/languages/ide/tools thare are DPI unaware https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows#dpi-unaware